Is $x^{y}\pm y$ ever equal to $\text{LCM}\left({1, 2, 3,\cdots, n}\right)$ when $n\geq5$, and where $y\geq2$?
Note: This question came in my mind.

Is $x^{y}\pm y$ ever equal to $\text{LCM}\left({1, 2, 3,\cdots,
> n}\right)$ when $n\geq5$, and where $y\geq2$?

I know that $2^{4}-4=\text{LCM}\left({1,2,3,4}\right)$, and is that the largest solution to $x^{y}\pm y=\text{LCM}\left({1,2,3,\cdots,n}\right)$, where $y\geq2$?
I have no idea, but I know these things:

If $x$ is even, then $y$ must be even and not be congruent to $2\pmod{4}$, as $\text{LCM}\left({1,2,3,\cdots,n}\right)$ is always divisible by $4$ when $n\geq4$.

If the last digit of $x$ is $6$, then $y$ must be $4\pmod{20}$ as the all powers of integers ending with $6$ ends with $6$ and $(10k+6)^{20b+4}$ always ends with $0$.


I did check the all values of $x ,y ,z$ from $5$ to $10^{4}$ using Pari GP, but it was not successful.

Can you provide the source for this question?

How many values of $n$ did you check?

@GerryMyerson I did check all values of $n$ up to $10^{4}$.
